# My exe created with pyinstaller flashes and terminates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have written small code in python for data scraping using selenium, and BeautifulSoup.

The code is working great in pyCharm but when I convert my file from .py to EXE using `pyinstaller example.py` command, it converts correctly but the EXE file  flashes and terminates and the code doesn't execute.

This is the result of the pyinstaller command:
[image]

Comment: Could you try running the same on a PyCharm terminal. You maybe using a virtual environment in PyCharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when there is an error being faced by the python script. Try running the **.py** module file in IDLE or by simple double clicking the **.py** .

I guess **pyCharm** creates a virtual environment which might be causing the issue.

Maybe try adding **try/except** for the code so that it doesn't flick away, rather shows the error.

Comment: when I try to execute EXE file from terminal it gives this error: \build\olx\python37.dll'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: That means the pyinstaller is not able to pack all the required modules and DLLs.
If you have python installed then, in a completely new directory, copy the .py, open the terminal and try `python olx.py`. If it works then in the same directory use `pyinstaller olx.py`. [Use `pip install pyinstaller` if necessary

Comment: I copied just olx.py in new directory on desktop and its working find with python olx.py. then used pyinstaller olx.py and created olx.exe not working and just flashes again with same error

Comment: Goto: c:\users\oasis3\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\ and copy the python37.dll and paste it in the build\olx folder in the **desktop**.

Comment: Also, use `pyinstaller --onefile olx.py` if you can. And check the standalone exe created in the **dist** folder

Comment: I installed pyinstaller again and now its working EXE file that is in .\dist\ folder

Comment: Did you use the --onefile argument? Also mark this as the answer if I was helpful.